# Java Comparable object with Priority Queue

Tags: java, interface, queue, comparable

I am trying to use a priority queue (java.util.PriorityQueue) on a custom class. I understand that the PriorityQueue class uses the Comparable interface, so I implemented it in my custom class:

```
public class State implements Comparable<State> {
    public int val;

    public State(){
        this.val = 0;
    }

    public int compareTo(State other){
        return this.val - other.val;
    }
}
```

And to use the queue, I did:

```
PriorityQueue<State> q = new PriorityQueue<State>();
q.add(myState1);
q.add(myState2);
// etc.
```

It compiles correctly, but I get this exception during runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: State cannot be cast to
java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
    at MapTable.search(MapTable.java:308)
    at Map.main(Map.java:67)
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can remember, this is how I would implement comparable. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Are you sure the `State` in the `Comparable<State>` is the right one, and not `java.lang.Thread.State` or `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.State` for example?

Comment: @amit wouldn't the exception print the qualified name of the class in that case? It appears that the issue is probably that he forgot to recompile `State`.

Comment: @oldrinb You are right, that did it! I assumed it would compile, since I use the object in several places before, but I guess it didn't for some reason. But compiling it separately did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @oldrinb: It is an answer. post it.

Comment: @Richard [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12342770/591495) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit) originally suggested in his comment a very wise piece of advice; essentially, make sure you're not referring to another class named `State` which is hiding your own `State` from view, e.g. `java.lang.Thread.State` and `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.State`. This is often the cause of many bugs, so make sure you remember this.

Unfortunately, it's not the case here. As I pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342539/java-comparable-object-with-priority-queue#comment16570753_12342539), the exception would print the *qualified* name of whatever other `State` as a part of the exception message in that case. Since the qualified name was `State`, it makes sense that you likely forgot to recompile `State`. :-)

Comment: Can you explain this in detail, I am getting the same error but couldn't understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly in my Eclipse ide.
Maybe you have imported a class State from a different package?